# In Scala, is it possible to use fold left to do summation up to certain index in the list?

Tags: scala, list, immutablelist

I am trying to find an effective way to do summation of the list up to the selected index.

```
var groupList : List[Int] = List(1,3,4,5)
```

What can i do to achieve if i select indexOf(2), it will do summation up to that index? ( 1 + 3 + 4) ?

Comment: `indexOf` searches for a value, and then returns the index of that value.  In your example, `indexOf(2)` would return -1 because there is no 2 in your List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
val idx = 2
groupList.take(idx+1).sum
// res3: Int = 8
```

Or for efficiency:

```
groupList.toIterator.take(idx+1)
// res4: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

groupList.toIterator.take(idx+1).sum
// res5: Int = 8
```

Comment: Ah, perfect..
I missed out the take in scala docs..
Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I have another question. What if i want sum between indexOf(1) to indexOf(2) for example?
Is there a scala list way to do, rather than using a forloop?
Thanks before

Comment: You can drop a few elements and take the intermediate elements you need, then do the sum. So maybe something like `groupList.drop(1).take(1).sum`.

Comment: Man, you are right...
My brain doesn't really work well today ..
Hahaha..
Thank you for the answer